# Dúvidas no combobox

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Tenho duas combobox, a primeira estão os gerente e a segunda tenho os coordenadores.

GERENTE - FABIO - ADRIANA - LEANDRO

COORDENADORES - TEREZA - GERALDO - GABRIELE - JOICE - VALDIR -ROSE - KATIA -LUCIA - PAULO - REBECA

Quando eu selecionar na combo gerente  Fabio 
Na combo coordenador terá que mostrar GABRIELE - LUCIA TEREZA

Quando eu selecionar na combo gerente  LEANDRO
Na combo coordenador terá que mostrar GERALDO - REBECA - JOICE

Quando eu selecionar na combo gerente  Adriana
Na combo coordenador terá que mostrar KATIA - PAULO - VALDIR

```
Sub PreencherComboboxCoord()
    Dim wsc    As Worksheet
    Dim wsr    As Worksheet
    Dim celula As Range
    Dim NGerente As String

    Set wsc = Sheets("Custos de 01 a 1310")
    Set wsr = Sheets("Resultado")

    wsc.Select
    wsc.Range("M2").Select 'Coordenador

     With Planilha3
        NGerente = .Cbo_Gerente.Value
       .Cbo_Coordenador.Clear
     End With

   Do

   With PlanCusto ' planilha onde vou extrair os dados


        On Error Resume Next
        Pesquisa = .Range("M2").Address & ":" & ActiveCell.Address
        contar = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(Pesquisa), ActiveCell.Text)

            With Planilha3 ' Resultado onde está as combox

                If contar <= 1 Then
                    If PlanCusto.Range(Pesquisa) = NGerente Then
                        .Cbo_Coordenador.AddItem ActiveCell.Text
                    End If
                End If

            End With

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        If ActiveCell.Value = Empty Then
            wsr.Select
            Exit Sub
        End If

  End With

  Loop
```

Ou seja cada Gerente tem seus coordenadores, e é este relacionamento que não estou fazer.

Aguardo retorno Grato

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o método .AddItem

```
        With Cbo_Coordenador
            .AddItem
            .List(.ListCount - 1) = "nome do coordenador1"
            .AddItem
            .List(.ListCount - 1) = "nome do coordenador2"
        End With
```

Este seria um método bem manual, o recomendável seria você criar uma tabela de relacionamento entre Gerente e Coordenador.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma, se estiver em um UserForm use o .AddItem quando a UserForm for iniciada (como o Francisco Salome mostrou), desta forma:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ComboBox_Gerente
        .AddItem
        .List(.ListCount - 1) = "Fabio"
        .AddItem
        .List(.ListCount - 1) = "Adriana"
        .AddItem
        .List(.ListCount - 1) = "Leandro"
    End With
End Sub
```

Assim, quando o UserForm for iniciado, o ComboBox_Gerente irá receber os itens Fabio, Adriana e Leandro. Após isso, adicione o seguinte código no ComboBox_Gerente

```
Private Sub ComboBox_Gerente_Change()

    ' Criar uma variavel com o nome "opc" (opção) como String (tipo de variavel para caracteres)'
    Dim opc As String

    ' A variavel opc é igual á opção selecionada no ComboBox_Gerente'
    opc = Me.ComboBox_Gerente.Text

    ' Se a variavel opc for igual a Fabio então o '
    'ComboBox_Coordenadores será igual a "GABRIELE - LUCIA - TEREZA", e o mesmo para as outras opções'
    If opc = "Fabio" Then
        Me.ComboBox_Coordenadores.Text = "GABRIELE - LUCIA - TEREZA"
        ElseIf opc = "Leandro" Then
            Me.ComboBox_Coordenadores.Text = "GERALDO - REBECA - JOICE"
            ElseIf opc = "Adriana" Then
                Me.ComboBox_Coordenadores.Text = "KATIA - PAULO - VALDIR"
    End If

End Sub
```

Assim, quando você selecionar uma das opções no ComboBox_Gerentes, o ComboBox_Coordenadores irá receber as opções referente aquele nome.

Espero ter ajudado!